# jQuery переход на страницу по уникальному id в базе данных

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Добрый день!
Имеется личный кабинет и возникла проблема с отчетами

Сделал переход на страничку /account/reports куда выводится список отчетов по user_id в базе, но у каждого отчета есть свой уникальный task_id и собственно вопрос в том как вывести расширенные отчеты по отдельности (по task_id) чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 'вывести подробный отчет' юзер переходил на страницу с этим отчетом (в данный момент выводятся все расширенные отчеты один за другим). Кнопки обрабатываются jQuery, в данный момент был реализован простой способ перехода на страничку с отчетами:

```
$('.tasks').on('click', '.fa-area-chart', function(){
        location.href='/account/reports';
    });
```

Comment: А при чём здесь jQuery или JavaScript вообще? Всё разруливается у вас на сервере. В строку браузера подставляете то, что на сервере вы принимаете и обрабатываете для отображения конкретного отчёта.

Comment: оффтоп, но не используйте `.fa-` классы для привязки событий. смените значок кнопки, придется менять код.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарии, просто все кнопки обрабатываются явой к примеру:

$('.task_edit').click(function () {
            var index = $(this).attr('data-index');
            var task = tasks[index];
            task_load(task);
            resize();
            $('.task').show();
        });

Хотелось бы реализовать через яву